# Serving domain and sub-domain with Nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, dns, subdomain

Basically I need to logically separate 2 sites on one hosting and one domain name registered. 
Firstly, I've set up a sub-domain using CNAME record. Then I've created 2 files for domain and sub-domain (no syntax errors, nginx restarted after changes):

subdomain.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name sub.domain.com;
index index.php index.html;
root /web/www/sub.domain.com;
access_log   off;
server_tokens off;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/webserv/var/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /webserv/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;}}
```

domain.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
index index.php index.html;
root /web/www/domain.com;
access_log   off;
server_tokens off;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/webserv/var/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /webserv/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;}}
```

But only one of them is working, and a request in browser to the other doesn't even get to nginx, and eventually it says the page load time was too long. What is the easiest way of doing this? Should several instances of nginx, php-fpm be used?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks fine, if the seconde file was enabled and wrong nginx would have triggered a server error, but from what you are saying the problem come from your domain name, maybe it is missconfigured or has not yet been propagated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, it wasn't working as I was using google public DNS on local machine(who would have thought)